# Site and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "orderBy"

Tags: php, yii

while i am fetching this records then getting this error how to solve it ?

[image]

public function actionIndex()
    {

```
        $query = Site::model();

        $pagination = new CPagination([
            'defaultPageSize' => 5,
            'totalCount' => $query->count(),
        ]);

        $countries = $query->orderBy('name')
            ->offset($pagination->offset)
            ->limit($pagination->limit)
            ->all();

        return $this->render('view', [
            'countries' => $countries,
            'pagination' => $pagination,
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your sql query? I think it should be 'ORDER BY'

Comment: $query = Site::model();
                
            $pagination = new CPagination([
                'defaultPageSize' => 5,
                'totalCount' => $query->count(),
            ]);

            $countries = $query->orderBy('name')
                ->offset($pagination->offset)
                ->limit($pagination->limit)
                ->all();

            return $this->render('view', [
                'countries' => $countries,
                'pagination' => $pagination,
            ]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should distinguish between yii1 and yii2.from your codes,you used yii1 and yii2 together.